# Calculare the mean of $X^2$

Tags: probability, expected-value

If I know that the mean of $X$ is $\mu$, is it true that the mean of $X^2$ is $\mu ^2$?

Comment: Say $X$ is $\pm 1$, each with probability $\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu's example [has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution).

Comment: Actually, my example was mistyped.  Should have written $X\in \{0,1\}$ with probability $\frac 12$ for each,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Normal random variable $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as an example, but the following formula is true for every random variable.

$$
\mathbb{E}[x^2] = Var(x) + \mathbb{E}^2[x]=Var(x)+\mu^2\neq \mu^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of variance, the mean of $X^2$ is actually $\mu^2+\sigma^2$. Your guess only works for constant variables.